# If f(x) is given, what would be the distribution of Y = 2X + 1?

Tags: self-study, cumulative-distribution-function

> If the random variable X has a continuous distribution with the
>   density $ f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\Bbb {1}_{(1, ∞)}(x)$, can you find the
>   distribution of $Y = 2X+1$?

**My attempt:**

$CDF(Y)$

$\Rightarrow P(Y\le y)$

$\Rightarrow P(2X + 1 \le y)$

$\Rightarrow P(X \le \frac{y-1}{2})$

$\Rightarrow \int_{1}^{(y-1)/2} f(x) dx$

$\Rightarrow \int_{1}^{(y-1)/2} \frac{1}{x^2} \Bbb 1_{(1, \infty)}(x) dx$

$\Rightarrow \int_{1}^{(y-1)/2} \frac{1}{x^2} dx$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{-2+1}[x^{-2+1}]_1^{(y-1)/2}$

$\Rightarrow 1 - \frac{2}{y-1}$ Ans.

---

Is it a correct approach?

Comment: No, you start off correctly but go wrong almost immediately because you don't seem to understand what is meant by a density function.

Comment: The line with "CDF(y)" on it is sort of okay. The next line is not, and the line after that has an additional error.

Comment: $PDF(Y\leq y)$ is nonsense. Start with $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=...$ and go on from there.  After that, *don't* substitute $2X+1$ for $y$. That's not what it's equal to.

Comment: That you get the value of a CDF as $5$ and that this does not cause any alarm bells to ring in your mind that something is awry, is worrisome.

Comment: anonymous .... The very first issue is that the argument of a pdf is not a logical condition, but a real number. It seems like you're conflating the probability of an event with the pdf. You need to try to get the concepts more clearly sorted out.

Comment: As a double check of your edited answer, note that an (easy) integration gives the CDF of $X$ as $$F_X(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}.$$  Since (by simple algebra) $X=(Y-1)/2$, substituting gives $$F_Y(y)=F_X((y-1)/2)=1-\frac{1}{(y-1)/2}=1-\frac{2}{y-1}.$$ Since working entirely with the CDFs avoids potentially problematic differentiation and re-integration, it's an approach worth learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make an early mistake.

$$\begin{align}
F_{Y}(y)&=\text{Pr}(Y\leq y)\\
&=\text{Pr}(2X+1\leq y)\\
&=\text{Pr}(X\leq \tfrac{1}{2}(y-1))\\
&=\int_{1}^{\tfrac{1}{2}(y-1)}f_{X}(u)\,du
\end{align}$$

Keep in mind that the bounds for $X$ are:

$$1\leq x <\infty$$

So the bounds for $Y$ will be:

$$3\leq y <\infty$$

Comment: Is the result $2 - \frac{2}{y-1}$ ?

Comment: @anonymous Your answer is close, but still incorrect. You should know that your answer is wrong because for this CDF $F_{Y}(3)=0,\, F_{Y}(\infty)=1$ and your answer imples $F_{Y}(3)=1,\, F_{Y}(\infty)=2$.

Comment: Then, I am quitting!

Comment: @anonymous I have nothing but admiration for your attitude.

Comment: I have a feeling that @anonymous is far from quitting, and he was kidding around. Anyway, I think you (@anonymous) have a new answer that wraps up the question, but you can also find an answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1382687/152225).

Answer (score 3):

**Since the transformation function is monotonic, we can find the CDF by using PDF transformation and integrating the transformed PDF.**

PDF Transformation:

$$ f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \Bigg|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} \Bigg|$$

For this situation, $g^{-1}(y) = \frac{y-1}{2}$, and by substitution:
$$f_X(g^{-1}(y)) = \frac{1}{((y-1)/2)^2} = \frac{4}{(y-1)^2}$$

The absolute value of the derivative of $g^{-1}(y)$ with respect to $y$ is easy:
\begin{align}
\Bigg|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} \Bigg| = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Plug components into the PDF Transformation formula above to get a transformed PDF of :
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{(y-1)^2} \quad \text{for} \quad 3 \leq y \lt \infty
\end{align}

Remembering to use transformed lower and upper bounds, we integrate to get the CDF. Line 3 employs **u-substitution** to simplify the integration:

\begin{align} 
F_Y(y) &=\int_{3}^{y} f_Y(t) \, dt\\  
&=\int_{3}^{y} \frac{2}{(t-1)^2} \, dt\\  
&=\int_{2}^{y-1} \frac{2}{u^2} \, du\\
&= -\frac{2}{u} \; \Bigg|_2^{y-1}\\
&= -\frac{2}{y-1} - (-\frac{2}{2})\\ 
&= 1 - \frac{2}{y-1} \quad \text{for} \quad 3 \leq y \lt \infty
\end{align}

Finally, we'll check the lower and upper bounds just to make sure we've fulfilled CDF validity requirements:

$$F_Y(3) = 1 - \frac{2}{2} = 0$$

$$F_Y(\infty) = 1 - \frac{2}{\infty} = 1$$